Exception while getting versioned table differences from an SOE
I have an SOE "Server Object Extension"
The exception happens when I call  versionedTable.Differences().
Exception message "Value does not fall within the expected range."
No idea what the problem is, and I can't find any similar issues with others.
public List<int> FindVersionDifferences(IWorkspace workspace, String childVersionName, String parentVersionName, String tableName, esriDifferenceType differenceType)

{
// Get references to the child and parent versions.
IVersionedWorkspace versionedWorkspace = (IVersionedWorkspace)workspace;
IVersion childVersion = versionedWorkspace.FindVersion(childVersionName);
IVersion parentVersion = versionedWorkspace.FindVersion(parentVersionName);

// Cast to the IVersion2 interface to find the common ancestor.
//IVersion2 childVersion2=(IVersion2)childVersion;
//IVersion commonAncestorVersion=childVersion2.GetCommonAncestor(parentVersion);

// Cast the child version to IFeatureWorkspace and open the table.
IFeatureWorkspace childFWS = (IFeatureWorkspace)childVersion;
ITable childTable = childFWS.OpenTable(tableName);

// Cast the common ancestor version to IFeatureWorkspace and open the table.
//IFeatureWorkspace commonAncestorFWS=(IFeatureWorkspace)commonAncestorVersion;
//ITable commonAncestorTable=commonAncestorFWS.OpenTable(tableName);

IFeatureWorkspace commonAncestorFWS = (IFeatureWorkspace)parentVersion;
ITable commonAncestorTable = commonAncestorFWS.OpenTable(tableName);

// Cast to the IVersionedTable interface to create a difference cursor.
IVersionedTable versionedTable = (IVersionedTable)childTable;
IDifferenceCursor differenceCursor = versionedTable.Differences
    (commonAncestorTable, differenceType, null);

// Create output variables for the IDifferenceCursor.Next method and a FID set.
//IFIDSet fidSet=new FIDSetClass();
IRow differenceRow = null;
long objectID = -1;
List<int> l = new List<int>();
// Step through the cursor, showing the ID of each modified row.
differenceCursor.Next(out objectID, out differenceRow);
while (objectID != -1)
{
    l.Add((int)objectID);
    differenceCursor.Next(out objectID, out differenceRow);
}

// fidSet.Reset();
// return fidSet;
return l; }

